# R:"Note: no visible binding for global variable" after devtools:use_data

Tags: r

I want to make a dataframe available to users of a package, as well as to functions of the package.

Starting from a new package I've used

```
devtools::use_data_raw("my_data")
```

This creates the file **data_raw/my_data.R**, which I edit as

```
my_data <- data.frame(x = runif(3), y = runif(3))

devtools::use_data(my_data, overwrite = TRUE)
```

After running the code above, a file **data/my_data.Rda** is created.

According to Hadley Wickham's [R Packages](https://r-pkgs.org/data.html#documenting-data) every file under **data/** is exported, and if I try

```
load_all()

my_data
```

I can see that this is the case. However if I now try to use the my_data dataframe inside a function in the package, say like **R/test_my_data.R**

```
test_my_data <- function {
  my_data
}
```

and then I run

```
devtools::check()
```

I get the infamous **no visible binding for global variable my_data** NOTE.

I appreciate there are many questions already on this topic but many are related to the cases where a tidy evaluation function is used, or data from another package is referred to. Why is R CMD check failing on the example above, and what's the correct way of sorting this out?

I'm aware that the

```
utils::globalVariables("my_data")
```

solution will avoid this NOTE, but I'd like to know if there's a proper way of informing R CMD check that **my_data** actually exists.

Comment: Do you have a file documenting my_data as data? See https://r-pkgs.org/data.html (chapter 8.2.1) for details.